# Couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: Permission denied

Tags: wireshark

When I start `wireshark` this is the message I get.

> Couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: Permission denied
>
> Error by extcap pipe:
>   ** (process:4740): WARNING **: Option '--remote-filter' requires an argument
>
> ** (process:4740): WARNING **: Missing parameter: --remote-host"

Comment: `dumpcap` is part of the `pcaputils` package. Install `pcaputils`.